# I cant understand this theorem in Linear Algebra SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

[SVD Theorem 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXg3r.jpg)

What does it mean in the last line for $\{Av_1,Av_2\cdots,Av_r\}$ is an orthogonal basis for the kernel/nullspace of $A$?

Comment: It's an orthogonal basis for the space ${\rm Im} A,$ i.e. the space spanned by the column vectors of  the matrix $A.$

Comment: @BazyliZuczek  how is the column vector space related to the nullspace of A?

Comment: The only relation is that the dimensions sum up to the dimension of the entire space. There is a relation of ${\rm Im}A$ with ${\rm ker} A^*,$ where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint matrix $a^*_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}.$ These spaces are orthogonal complements to each other. Do you need a reference ? I can look for an appropriate textbook.

Comment: What are you talking about? It states clearly that $\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_r\}$ is an orthogonal basis for the **column space** of $A$, not that it is a basis for the null space of $A$.

Comment: @user1531Shane Loboas is a new contributor. He mixed up the terms "Col" and "ker".